# sending post data via PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with this code:

```
function phpbbCurlLogin($username, $password) {

    $url = WEB_INDEX . '/forum/ucp.php';

    $postdata = sprintf(
        "mode=login&login=Login&username=%s&password=%s&redirect=%s"
        , $username
        , $password
        , WEB_INDEX
    );

    $cu = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($cu);
    curl_close($cu);

    return $result;
}
```

It works fine on localhost but not on the server. The server version simply returns nothing. (No errors, no warnings. Nothing.)

The weird part is: if I remove these two lines:

```
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

then the server version will return the content. But without the post data this function simply becomes useless.

What may be wrong here? Why I'm not able to send the post data? Any ideas?

P.S. I'm not sure if this info useful or not, but localhost runs on **PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13** while server has **PHP 5.2.17**

Answer (score 0):

Don't build your own POST string. Curl can do it perfectly fine without your help:

```
$postdata = array(
  'mode' => 'login',
  'login' => 'Login'
  'username' => $username,
  'password' => $password,
  'redirect' => WEB_INDEX
);


curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

If you take out the `_POST` and `_POSTFIELDS` opts, then curl will default to doing a `GET` request, and you'll probably just get the html of the login form. If you get a blank page when using POST, then you should turn on PHP error_reporting and display_errors options, and/or check the server logs to see what blew up. White page = something's wrong, and PHP's been configured to not say anything about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any difference of whether I use _$postdata_ as an array or as a string. The main problem still remains.

Comment: so start checking log and turn on php's debugging options. you can ask all the questions you want here, but the answers are right there on the server if only you'd actually go looking for them.